# Kafka crashing after upgrade

Tags: apache-kafka

I upgraded my kafka from 2.2.1 to 3.1.0.
After upgrade one of the broker stopped having below exception.

```
2022-05-09 13:36:15,051 ERROR kafka.server.ReplicaManager: [ReplicaManager broker=344] Error processing append operation on partition grpc_flow_logs_prod-0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$4(LogValidator.scala:428)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$3(LogValidator.scala:426)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$2(LogValidator.scala:426)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$1(LogValidator.scala:422)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed(LogValidator.scala:407)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.validateMessagesAndAssignOffsets(LogValidator.scala:112)
        at kafka.log.UnifiedLog.$anonfun$append$2(UnifiedLog.scala:802)
        at kafka.log.UnifiedLog.append(UnifiedLog.scala:1707)
        at kafka.log.UnifiedLog.appendAsLeader(UnifiedLog.scala:718)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$appendRecordsToLeader$1(Partition.scala:1057)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.appendRecordsToLeader(Partition.scala:1045)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$appendToLocalLog$6(ReplicaManager.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendToLocalLog(ReplicaManager.scala:912)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendRecords(ReplicaManager.scala:583)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleProduceRequest(KafkaApis.scala:658)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:169)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:75)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I assume you followed the upgrade steps?  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade Particularly around the versions about log format version changes?

Comment: yes, It is as per documentation. log.message.format.version was not set previously so I didn't configure it during the upgrade. Only inter.broker.protocol.version is required as per documentation.